# Creating meta language with Java

Tags: java, metaprogramming

guys! I need to create some sort of meta language which I could embed in XML and then parse with Java. For example:

```
<code>
    [if value1>value2 then "Hello, Bob!" else "Hello, Jack"]
</code>
```

or

```
 <code>
     [if value1+2>value2 return true]
 </code>
```

I need to implement conditional statements,arithmetics.

Any suggestions where should I start looking?

Comment: Java is not really the language for something like this. If you must use the JVM, try a Clojure, as Lisp makes this stuff easy.

Comment: @Mike Lisp makes ANYTHING easy? ;-)

Comment: I am starting to wonder about what you are trying to solve here... Neither writing dynamic content in XML nor parsing XML while reacting on he contents does require scripting... Or does it?

Comment: can anyone please say that what the meta language and object language in this code are?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java has a built-in JavaScript interpreter:

```
ScriptEngine jsEngine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
jsEngine.put("value1", 8);
jsEngine.put("value2", 9);
String script = "if(value1 + 2 > value2) {'Foo'} else {'Bar'}";
final Object result = jsEngine.eval(script);
System.out.println(result);  //yields "Foo" String
```

Of course you are free to both load the script from anywhere you need and to provide it with any context (`value` and `value2` in this example) you want.

See also [Scripting for the Java Platform](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting) article.

Answer (score 5):

A user here, [Bart Kiers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50476/bart-kiers). Wrote a [tutorial](http://bkiers.blogspot.com/2011/03/creating-your-own-programming-language.html) about creating a simple language in Java with ANTLR.

Answer (score 1):

Java has a scripting API that you could use for this. Lookup the API documentation of the package `javax.script`.

You could include code in for example JavaScript in the `code` element, and execute that using the scripting API.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to develop your own language, start off with the [interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern) pattern.  If you just want to leverage somebody else's language in your Java code, look to integration ala JSP style embedded languages.

Answer (score 1):

It is almost certain that a homemade language **would suck**, especially in the long run, so don't roll something on your own.

There are several jsp-like frameworks available, maybe one of those would do the trick:

[JSTL/JSP EL (Expression Language) in a non JSP (standalone) context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91692/jstl-jsp-el-expression-language-in-a-non-jsp-standalone-context)

Comment: Don't kick the guy in the crotch. Such language would not necessarily "suck", only a naively implemented parser would.

Comment: I'm not kicking anyone, just drawing my conclusions from observations made... It will not *necessarily* suck, it's just very likely that it will end up that way... :-)