# can I explicitly invoke EL on a string (java)

Tags: java, string, el

I am looking for a way to take a string like:
`"pleas take this ${date.object}."`
and a dictionary that has the key "object"

and replacing as EL does.

i.e. if `"object"=>"bag"` then I want to get the string `"pleas take this bag."`

I know I can do this using explicit string replacement but was looking for a way to utilize the same engine used by EL.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91692/jstl-jsp-el-expression-language-in-a-non-jsp-standalone-context

Comment: Is this in the context of a Java web application executed by a Servlet Engine, or in some standalone application?

Answer (score 3):

MessageFormat does something similuar. May be you can use this?

Example:

```
 MessageFormat.format("pleas take this {0} or may be this {1}", object, object2);
```

Comment: This does not answer my Q. As it assumes I control the string structure and object fields.