# Java: How to evaluate an EL expression - standalone (outside any web framework) without implementing interfaces?

Tags: java, el, evaluation

I'd like to use EL in my application. But I can't find any howto. I usually end up needing some interface for which I don't have an implementation.

I have a map of objects, and I want a string expression like Hello, `${person.name}` to be evaluated to a string.

How can I achieve that, using any of Commons EL, javax.el, OGNL, or such? Must be a standalone library.

And I *know* [Java: using EL outside J2EE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91692/jstl-jsp-el-expression-language-in-a-non-jsp-standalone-context), and have seen [JSTL/JSP EL (Expression Language) in a non JSP (standalone) context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91692/jstl-jsp-el-expression-language-in-a-non-jsp-standalone-context). That is not what I'm looking for.

What I am looking for is an example of what dependency to add, and then how to initialize a parser which will have:

```
private static String evaluateEL( String expr, Map<String, String> properties );
```

and allow me to do:

```
String greet = evaluateEL("Hello ${person.name}", 
     new HashMap(){{
       put("person", new Person("Ondra"));
     }}
);
```

And I need it to use some rational value, e.g. `""` on `null` instead of throwing NPE or so.

Comment: While not exactly EL, [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/) has a similar syntax and feature set.

Comment: Also Velocity has a similar syntax as EL.

Comment: OGNL might be it, but their website doesn't work ATM.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's quite a bunch of EL engines, of which most implement Java Expression Language API.

- Commons EL (http://jakarta.apache.org/commons/el/)
  Implementation of the JSP EL API that's existed forever. This library can be found in many JSP containers (Tomcat for example) or used as a foundation for within many vendor's J2EE servers.
- OGNL (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/)
  One of the most expressive ELs available today and widely used with WebWork (Struts 2) and Tapestry.
- MVEL (https://github.com/mvel/mvel)
  A newcomer to EL which is part of the MVFlex/Valhalla project. Features look more in line with OGNL's offering with method invocation and some interesting regular expression support.
- (Unified) Expression Language (https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr341/index.html and http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=245)
  Standard expression language first introduced in Java EE 5 (EL 2.1) and enhanced in Java EE 6 (EL 2.2) and Java EE 7 (EL 3.0). Reference implementation available from Glassfish project - 
  [Unified Expression Language](https://uel.java.net/).
- JEXL (http://jakarta.apache.org/commons/jexl/)
  An implementation based on Velocity's parser. Because of this, it acts more like a limited templating solution with things like method invocation.

*[Source](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/jhook/archive/2006/11/el_comparisons.html)*

For now I ended up with this code using **BeanUtils** - ugly but works.

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public static class SimpleEvaluator implements IExprLangEvaluator {
    private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger( SimpleEvaluator.class );

    @Override
    public String evaluateEL( String template, Map<String, String> properties ) {

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer( template );
        String text = st.nextToken("${");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        // Parse the template: "Hello ${person.name} ${person.surname}, ${person.age}!"
        do{
            try {
                sb.append(text);
                if( ! st.hasMoreTokens() )
                    break;

                // "${foo.bar[a]"
                String expr  = st.nextToken("}");
                // "foo.bar[a].baz"
                expr = expr.substring(2);
                // "foo"
                String var = StringUtils.substringBefore( expr, ".");

                Object subject = properties.get( var );

                // "bar[a].baz"
                String propPath = StringUtils.substringAfter( expr, ".");

                sb.append( resolveProperty( subject, propPath ) );

                text = st.nextToken("${");
                text = text.substring(1);
            } catch( NoSuchElementException ex ){
                // Unclosed ${
                log.warn("Unclosed ${ expression, missing } : " + template);
            }
        } while( true );

        return sb.toString();
    }

    // BeanUtils
    private String resolveProperty( Object subject, String propPath ) {
        if( subject == null ) return "";

        if( propPath == null || propPath.isEmpty() ) return subject.toString();

        try {
            return "" + PropertyUtils.getProperty( subject, propPath );
        } catch(     IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException ex ) {
            log.warn("Failed resolving '" + propPath + "' on " + subject + ":\n    " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            return "";
        }
    }

}// class SimpleEvaluator
```

Answer (score 5):

I found one at http://juel.sourceforge.net/guide/start.html .
Still not exactly 1-liner, but close.

```
ExpressionFactory factory = new de.odysseus.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl();
de.odysseus.el.util.SimpleContext context = new de.odysseus.el.util.SimpleContext();
context.setVariable("foo", factory.createValueExpression("bar", String.class));
ValueExpression e = factory.createValueExpression(context, "Hello ${foo}!", String.class);
System.out.println(e.getValue(context)); // --> Hello, bar!
```

Maven deps:

```
    <!-- Expression language -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.odysseus.juel</groupId>
        <artifactId>juel-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.odysseus.juel</groupId>
        <artifactId>juel-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Use `<artifactId>juel-impl</artifactId>`, otherwise you'll have two conflicting EL-APIs.

Comment: Based on the comment I have changed `artifactId` from `juel` to `juel-impl`, but without testing it.

Comment: I have updated the versions. Looks like the JUEL impl has changed `groupId` to `de.odysseus.juel`.