# Java Command Window Matlab Alike

Tags: java, matlab

In Matlab, whenever I enter a variable name into command window, it displays the value of that variable so far, very useful feature. So that, I tried to add the same feature in java. That is, I want to display the value of any kind of variable(int, double, value of array such as signal[4] ) when the user enters something. If entered variable does not exist, it gives error or blows up. More precisely, I want to add something similar to the code below at the end of my project.

```
while(true){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Yep? : ");
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println(s + " = value of that entered variable");
        }
```

Obviously, It is not as easy as it sounds but that is the reason I am asking in here. Is there any easy way to add this simplicity?

Answer (score 0):

No. For java, this is pretty meaningless, since the

- The scope is the one of your loop
- it could be at best applied to the names of fields via the reflection API
- but for local variables, the name is lost during compilation (if the compiler likes to optimize, it could remove the variable completely).

I could imagine that upon binding a reasonably chosen set of objects into an Java Expression Language (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html) - using a variable mapper (see [JSTL/JSP EL (Expression Language) in a non JSP (standalone) context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91692/jstl-jsp-el-expression-language-in-a-non-jsp-standalone-context)) you could achieve something what you in a simple way.